# .Net WinForm System Beep on a 64 Bit OS

Tags: .net, windows, 64-bit, beep

My application needs to beep when validation fails so the user (who may be several feet away) may hear it. I'd like to use the `Console.Beep()` but this is [unavailable in a x64 environment (see the remarks)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8hftfeyw.aspx). There may or may not be speakers in/at the computer, so I can't use `System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play()`.

The current target platform is a x86 environment, but I'd like to have the ability for the application to run in x64 also.

Is there a way to do this or should I just give up?

**Edit**: Added link to the method.

Comment: Can please tell, why Console.Beep() will not work on x64 environments?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Beep has been removed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679277(VS.85).aspx) as a native function from all x64 platforms (so no managed version of course), there was a Microsoft Connect issue that petitioned to return it.

We use a different trick to discover servers, we remote eject the dvd drive, and the drive with the tray open is the one were looking for :)

**[EDIT]**
Larry Osterman has a great article about this: [What's up with the beep driver in Windows 7](http://blogs.msdn.com/larryosterman/archive/2010/01/04/what-s-up-with-the-beep-driver-in-windows-7.aspx)

Comment: So there's no way to force a Beep in a x64 platform?

Comment: looks like it, there might be a 3rd party beep driver out there but i could not find one.

Answer (score 0):

Playing one of the standard windows sounds might be a better approach. The following article shows how (it only takes a couple lines):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y171b18(VS.100).aspx

If you wanted to stay within theme, you could check the windows registry for the current sound scheme, and play the appropriate sound to fit your need.

Comment: I don't know whether the machine that will be used will have a speaker or wont be muted (like my machine) otherwise this would be a good fit.

Comment: Coming from the users perspective, if I don't have the option of muting annoying application sounds, I'd be pretty frustrated. I would call having the option a HUGE bonus for the user. Its a bad idea to try and control what a user hears and what pops up on the users screen. Microsoft has spent years fine tuning those capabilities to give users the utmost control of annoying things like that.

Comment: This is a request from the user. They were complaining that they couldn't hear when there had been an error in the previous version. Now that I've been tasked with updating, I need to accommodate those issues.

Comment: But I completely agree, that's why I have my computers always muted unless I'm watching something.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Console.Beep()` method described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8hftfeyw(v=vs.110).aspx

Make sure that you run the executable as an administrator (escalated privileges)

Comment: Let me quote the OP: *"I'd like to use the Console.Beep() but this is __unavailable__ in a x64 environment (see the remarks)"*. Next time read the question first.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Sse3LxD.png
Does this qualify as an x64 OS? How about you try my suggested method before assuming I didn't read the question first. Granted I'm not running Vista or XP but .Beep() is running on a x64 OS.